# What is wrong with my custom Entity form validation?

Tags: 8, entities

I add

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
}
```

to MymoduleMyentityForm.php which starts with

```
namespace Drupal\association\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
```

Then I run the form and when I submit it, I get this error: *Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "Entity validation was skipped." at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/JdP8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php line 770*

Any idea why?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation of `ContentEntityForm::validateForm`:

> Button-level validation handlers are highly discouraged for entity
>   forms, as they will prevent entity validation from running. If the
>   entity is going to be saved during the form submission, this method
>   should be manually invoked from the button-level validation handler,
>   otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Even if you don't use button-level validation this should be the cause for the exception. Did you call the parent method?

```
parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);
```

If you don't run the entity field validation in some way the exception is thrown.